# Remove docker-compose stack name from Traefik V2 defaultRule

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

In Traefik V2 the .Name attribute in the defaultRule=Host( .Name .. )
prints the containerName-stackName instead only the containerName when using docker-compose.

Any idea how this can be removed ?
This is my current rule:

```
- --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{ trimPrefix `/` .Name }}.containers.myorg.com`)
```

If my compose stack's name is monitoring, and the container is grafana this creates:

```
grafana-monitoring.containers.myorg.com
```

instead of

```
grafana.containers.myorg.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me:

```
- --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{if index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.containers.myorg.com{{else}}{{ trimPrefix `/` .Name }}.containers.myorg.com{{end}}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you defined `container_name` in the docker compose, you can use:

```
- --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{.ContainerName}}.containers.myorg.com`)
```

otherwise as FreshMike said this also works

```
- --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service"}}.containers.myorg.com`)
```